# Import Audio CD is not working

Tags: music, audio-cd

I have problems importing a CD with noise. The music player is showing  every title, but when I click on the import button nothing happened.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

cd /home/username/.local/share/noise/ and delete the Database(*.db) in this folder. After this step you can import your mp3 files again.